# Calling a fragment after DialogFragment was finished

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have Fragment A. On Fragment A I launch DialogFragment. After completing DialogFragment and pressing a confirm button I would like to go to Fragment B.
How should I go about it? Currently I am thinking of returning a boolean from DialogFragment to Fragment A, and then in an instant launch Fragment B from Fragment A. I do not know how would I observe that boolean in a way that, when it changes, Fragment B is called from Fragment A.

Currenty I know how to start Fragment B  by button.onClickListener{}, i would like to achieve booleanAttribute.onChangeListener{}

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's simple

I have several ways to handle it:

```
1.high-order function or interface listener
```

you can pass a call back to dialogfragment when you are creating instance and override onDismiss method and invoke it

```
2. use LiveData or Observable
```

you can create a livedata in parent and observe it and pass it to DialogFragment and then handle changing state like STATE_SHOW or STATE_DISMISS or etc.

Comment: Could you please clarify some more?
Currenty I know how to start Fragment B by button.onClickListener{}, i would like to achieve booleanAttribute.onChangeListener{}

How exactly would I implement LiveData, and change it when in DialogFragment?

Comment: ok, I'll write an example in each case, please wait :))